Designing Filename prefix on GCP Pub Sub as YYYY/MM/DD when writing data to cloud storage
While writing stream data to storage, I want to print it to the folder of the relevant year, month and day. Pub/Sub in subscriptions
Which function should I use in Filename prefix settings?
I expect folder pattern should be 2024/4/20.

--

I expect folder pattern should be 2024/4/20.

In short: it's not possible. What's the frequency of your message? Do you have a large volume per minute?

Yes, i have huge response.

This is now possible using the filename_datetime_format setting on Cloud Storage subscriptions. You can find the reference for how to specify the filename_datetime_format here: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/create-cloudstorage-subscription#file_names
Unfortunately the setting is not yet available in the GCP UI, but you can specify it in API calls or via the gcloud CLI: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/pubsub/subscriptions/create
For your use case, you could include a matcher string like YYYY/MM/DD in your datetime format, which would produce something like 2024/04/20 in a generated filename.

The filename itself will have the formatted datetime, but how can you also reflect that in the filepath (ie. the prefix)?

@Gabriel could you share an example of what filepath + filename you are trying to generate?

I'm trying to have the cloud storage subscription save Avro files into a hive-partitioned GCS. For this reason, I'm trying to have files such as year=2024/month=05/day=17/<inconsequential file name>.avro

Unfortunately, including prefixes like "year=", "month=", etc. isn't currently supported. Are the prefixes needed? If so, you can file a feature request for this support describing your use case and it will be considered, thank you! https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/getting-support#file_bugs_or_feature_requests
